# Ext JS get grid's selected row

Tags: extjs, grid

On `someButton` click event I want to get the selected row of `someGrid` and `Do something` in event-handler dependent on that. How can I do that? I tried using

```
var index = someGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection().selectedIndex; 
var index = someGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection().selected;
```

Both of this lines of code return empty objects.

```
flex: 1,
                xtype: 'grid',
                style: 'margin: 10px 5px;',
                store: 'CL.Store.VendorServiceLimits',
                itemId: 'vendorServiceLimitsGrid',
                columns: [
                    { text: Labels.Vendors.MIN_AMOUNT, dataIndex: 'MinOperationAmount', flex: 1 },
                    { text: Labels.Vendors.MAX_AMOUNT, dataIndex: 'MaxOperationAmount', flex: 1 },
                    { text: Labels.Vendors.MAX_TRANS_PER_DAY, dataIndex: 'MaxOperationsPerDay', flex: 1 },
                    { text: Labels.Vendors.OPERATION_TYPE, dataIndex: 'OperationType', flex: 1 },
                    { text: Labels.Vendors.PERIOD, dataIndex: 'Period', flex: 1 },
                    { dataIndex: 'Id', hidden: true }
                ],
```

Comment: Please provide grid's code.

Comment: As i see you create it dynamically. So you need to create something like this: <SelectionModel>
                <ext:RowSelectionModel ID="RowSelectionModel1" />
            </SelectionModel>

Comment: Can you use `store.indexOf(record)` in conjunction with `selModel.getSelection()`?  i.e. `store.indexOf(grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0])`

Comment: @kevhender +props for the `grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0]` reminder. Was trying to quickly find that when I came here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is is what you are looking for :

```
listeners:{
 click:function(){
       var grid = Ext.getCmp('grid');
       var selection= grid.getSelectionModel(); 
       items=[];
       for(i=0;i < grid.store.getCount();i++){  
          if(selection.isSelected(i)){
            items.push({ 
               "MinOperationAmount"   : grid.store.getAt(i).data.MinOperationAmount,
               "MaxOperationAmount"   : grid.store.getAt(i).data.MaxOperationAmount
             });
      }
    }
 }
}
```

In items array,you will be getting handle to all the selected records.Here i have pushed only two columns data.You can add other columns too.

Comment: This would work but It's too expensive. I mean I want to get just a number which will be indicating the row of the grid which is selected. grid has an event called cellclick which recieves parameter called rowIndex. that is what I'm looking for ! But I don't want to use the grids cellclick event to handle the thing I want to do. I want to use buttons click event instead

Answer (score 0):

In order for using `getSelectionModel` you must have `SelectionModel`
So you have to add the above.

```
 <SelectionModel>
            <ext:RowSelectionModel ID="RowSelectionModel1" runat="server" />
  </SelectionModel>
```

The above is working for `RowSelection`. There are other examples if you want to use checkbox.
The above xml is taken from ext.net.